# React context being lost after redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state, react-context

Creating context

```
export default React.createContext({
user:null,
login:()=>{}
})
```

Context controller

```
export default class ContextHandler extends Component{
state = {
    user: null,
}
logout = () => {
    this.setState({
        user: null
    })
}

login = user => {
    this.setState({
        user: user
    })
};

render(){
    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user: this.state, login: this.login, logout: this.logout }} >
            {this.props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component{
render() {
    return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Header} />
                        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
                        <Route path="/profile" exact component={UserProfile} />
                        <Route path="/inputform" exact component={InputForm} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render((
<ContextHandler>
    <App/>
</ContextHandler>
),
document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

User Profile Page

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.context.user) {
        return ( <Redirect to = "/login"/> )
    }

    else{
        this.setState({
            loading:true
        })
        getUserEntries(this.context.user.token,(entries)=>{
            if(entries !== null){
                this.setState({
                    userEntries:entries
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

   render() {
    let samples, producers
    if(!this.context.user){
        return(
            <Redirect to="/login"/>
        )
    }

    if (this.state.userEntries) {
        samples = (this.buildList(this.state.userEntries.samples))
        producers = (this.buildList(this.state.userEntries.producers))
    }
```

Once I log in I'm directed to the user page with the correct context. Once I navigate to another page and try go back to the user profile page the context is lost. and i have to login again??

The only two components consuming the context are the nav bar and the user profile page.
Note: I am using the new 16.6 context API i.e no consumer tags in render.

Comment: What does `navigate` mean here? In your app or total page refresh?

Comment: Either I click on a navigation option which uses a Route to load a different page or just change the url to change pages.

Comment: what do you mean by `the context is lost` ? does this mean that the value user is lost ? Can you show us your UserProfile component ?

Comment: The state is set to null, as if I never logged in.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @prestonsmith Yes, I added cookies to my application. The only reason was that the entire DOM tree was being rebuilt on my local host. (rookie mistake)

Comment: can you working solution abit in detail as I am also stuck here